# In R how to pass parameters to a functions like plotXtabs2 as strings?

Tags: r, function, eval

[PlotXTabs2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CGPfunctions/vignettes/Using-PlotXTabs2.html) is a function to plot crosstab proportions between categorical variables where there are 3 minimum required parameters

PlotXTabs2(
  data,
  x,
  y)

data as data frame, x, and y column names from this data frame.

I want to call it inside a loop where the column names x, y, are going be strings coming from dataframe colnames(), something like ....

varscat = colnames(df)

```
for(i in 1:(length(varscat)-1)) 
{
  for(j in (i+1):length(varscat))
  {
     tmp <- df[,c(myvars[varscat[i]], myvars[varscat[j]])]

     # ...

     PlotXTabs2( df, x=myvars[varscat[i]], y=myvars[varscat[j]] ) 
 }
}
```

I've been trying to follow examples with eval, do.call with no success, most of them are related to cases where the intended use is to write functions to accept parameters as strings.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!!` from `rlang`:

```r
library(CGPfunctions)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'lme4':
#>   method                          from
#>   cooks.distance.influence.merMod car 
#>   influence.merMod                car 
#>   dfbeta.influence.merMod         car 
#>   dfbetas.influence.merMod        car
library(ggplot2)
out <- lapply(combn(colnames(mpg), 2, simplify = FALSE), 
       function(z) PlotXTabs2( mpg, !!z[1], !!z[2]) )
out[[3]] ## example plot from the list
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:**

The order of variable pairs affects the way the plots are generated. We can specifically select the first and second element of the pairs with a function like this:

```r
plotPairs <- function(xvals, yvals, data, ...){
    pairs <- as.list(data.frame(t(expand.grid(xvals, yvals))))
    lapply(pairs, function(z) PlotXTabs2( data, !!z[1], !!z[2], ...))
}

out <- plotPairs(
    xvals = c("vs", "cyl", "gear"),
    yvals = c("am", "carb"),
    data = mtcars, 
    ylab = NULL,
    perc.k = 1,
    palette = "Set2")
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but why when I try to apply the same for for ggplot it doesn't?  >>    vx = "mpg"
  vy = "disp"
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=!!vx, y= !!vy)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: `?\`!!\`` will give you examples how to pass that - yeah, it is a bit complicated, but this is how it would work in that case: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=!!sym(vx), y=!!sym(vy))) + geom_bar(stat="identity") `

Comment: In my answer, replacing `PlotXTabs2( mpg, !!z[1], !!z[2])` with `PlotXTabs2(mpg, !!sym(z[1]), !!sym(z[2]))` would also work; maybe that would be safer, as a generalization.

Comment: Glad you find the package helpful @jcarlos.  You may also want to look at the last poart of the vignette on using `pmap` to cross variables as well as the `cross2_var_vectors` helper function https://ibecav.github.io/CGPfunctions/reference/cross2_var_vectors.html

Answer (score 2):

Felt obligated as the function author to show how I typically use it, and avoid quotation woes.  The vignettes and help files show more complex examples where you can use `pmap` to build titles etc, etc.

```r
library(CGPfunctions)

# you can build by column number
# cross2_var_vectors(mtcars, 9, c(2, 10:11))
# or column name
# cross2_var_vectors(mtcars, "am", c("cyl", "gear", "carb"))
# build the vectors by hand
x2 <- c("am", "carb")
y2 <- c("vs", "cyl", "gear")
# cross2_var_vectors(mtcars, x2, y2, verbose = TRUE)

variables_list <- cross2_var_vectors(mtcars, x2, y2)

plotlist <- purrr::map2(
  .x = variables_list$lista
  .y = variables_list$listb,
  .f = CGPfunctions::PlotXTabs2,
  data = mtcars,
  ylab = NULL,
  perc.k = 1,
  palette = "Set2"
)

plotlist[[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I wonder whether you could either pass a larger default `B` parameter to the `fisher.test` used by `sjstats::crosstable_statistics`, or allow the user to choose that - or to allow the choice of method "phi" (chiq.test) and "auto", since B=2000 frequently gives quite variable p-values when `sjstats::crosstable_statistics` picks "fisher". This would make the results a bit more reproducible. In your example plot above, p easily varies between .005 and .015, for example. With `B = 1E6`, it mostly varies between .0090 and .0092, hence remains much closer to the .0091 calculated by chisq.

Comment: I'll take a look.  Could you do me a favor and put it here, so I don't forget, I seldom focus on p values anymore.